# How does mod_rewrite validate whether the request is a file or directory?

Tags: mod-rewrite

Given the conditions and rule below,how does mod_rewrite validate whether the request is a file or directory?

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My interpretation is that if the request is not a file **AND** not a directory then process the rewrite rule which has the pattern any character that is not a question mark, substitute as a querystring with the back-reference `$1`

Isn't every request a file or directory e.g. index.php, style.css, media, etc? Shouldn't the condition be

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which would read that if the request is a file **OR** a directory then process the rewrite rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) `REQUEST_FILENAME` is:

> The full local filesystem path to the file or script matching the
>   request, if this has already been determined by the server at the time
>   REQUEST_FILENAME is referenced. Otherwise, such as when used in
>   virtual host context, the same value as REQUEST_URI.

You could think of it like a path that may or may not exist on the real file system. An incoming request could look something like http:\\example.com\blah.php. If that is a real file then you are saying you want to use it. But there may not be a real file called blah.php on the server. In which case, instead of returning a 404 error you pass the request onto a file called index.php.

In short you shouldn't think of the parts of a URL as files or directories. They need not map to real file system paths (though they often do).

Comment: Thanks matthew. So let me understand what you are saying. Taking your example of `http:\\example.com\blah.php` with the conditions and rule of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`, you mean to say it if `blah.php` exists then use `blah.php`. IF it does not exist, then redirect the user to `index.php`. Is that right?

Comment: Correct, although technically the first part is simply the default behavior, the ruleset only explicitly says the second part.

Comment: Sorry don't quite follow what you mean by the first and second part? Also I tried the rule as-is and it does not appear to load any of the CSS files, Javascript files, etc unless I do `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d RewriteRule ^([^?]*)`. Why is that?

Comment: The ruleset only speaks to rewriting if the path doesn't exist, it says nothing about what to do if it does. If the file does exist, the rule does not match, by default (assuming no later rules) that file is served.

Comment: Not knowing how your files are actually structured I couldn't say why other files wouldn't load... if you're able, turn on the rewrite log for testing and it'll help you see how the rewrite rules are being applied. If nothing else, make sure you check your regular error log as it may tell you where things are going wrong.

Comment: I am now more confused. I thought the conditions meant that if the path, file or directory exists then to use the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22417/discussion-between-peanutsmonkey-and-matthew)